# Can Django accept and validate multiple values in one field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

First off, I am very familiar with using ForiegnKeys in my data models.  I don't need or want that complex of a relationship in this particular scenario.  (I'm capturing name-servers and NTP-servers for a DHCP service.  A table to capture such servers to use as a FK would be overkill.)

What I do need is the UI bits to capture multiple (say zero to 4) IP addresses and store them into a single CharField as a comma-separated list.  I know I can do this via a simple CharField and clean() that splits on the commas and checks each IP or uses a regex that expects multiple values.  But, is there a better way (with Django 2.0)?  I've looked at ComboField and MultiValueField but the examples are few and my impression is those are rigid for how many values are expected.  Like if GenericIPAddressField didn't exist, you might possibly use MultiValueField to verify each of the 4 octets.

This will be used in the Admin site, if that matters.

EDIT: clarify the need for UI (vs storage)

Answer (score 0):

a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) might solve your problem; you can store all your IPs in a single json object

Comment: That would work nicely for the storage, but I see I was unclear that it's the UI I am concerned with.